# Неправильно работает реклама AdMob в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, admob, unity3d-ui

При прохождении 6 сцен должна запускаться видео реклама с возможностью пропуска через 5 секунд но запускается межстраничная реклама (картинка) на 0.5секунд и пропадает.

P.S 6 сцен проходит, запускается реклама на 0.5 секунд и сразу пропадает.
P.S.S Только что зашёл в playmode`е, реклама запускается но сразу пропускается и переходит на новую сцену.

Вот непосредственно сам код (Ключ тестовый для видео):

```
public class InterAd : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    private string interstitialUnityId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433";

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitialUnityId);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код лучше бы отформатировать с нормальными отступами. В текущем виде он не очень читабелен и содержит синтаксическую ошибку, то есть не скомпилируется.

Comment: @aepot исправил, а какая синтаксическая ошибка может быть?

Comment: Я ее исправил..